# Why does Emacs make it difficult for me to have two frames open the same buffer?

Tags: emacs

I have 2 frames. I switch the buffer in first frame to buffer A. When I try to switch the buffer in the second frame to buffer A, Emacs brings the first frame forward. What I want is to open buffer A in both frames. Is there a setting that makes Emacs bring the other frame forward when buffer A is already opened in it?

Comment: How exactly are you switching buffers?

Comment: And what version of Emacs?  I'm unable to reproduce the behavior you describe with Emacs 23.3.  Try starting a new Emacs with `emacs -Q` to see if you've made some customization that's causing this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a feature of “Ido”, which you seem to be using.

Just go to “Customize Emacs”, and in the group “Convenience / Ido”, change the settings “Ido Default Buffer Method” and “Ido Default File Method”, which surely are now set to “Raise frame if already shown”.

Comment: This is also the behavior of `iswitchb-buffer`.